Left shift of transfinite sequences
Background: Let $(D,\, {\leq})$ be a partial order. We consider sequences $a = (a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$  of elements of $D$. For two sequences $a$ and $b$, we lift $\leq$ (point-wise) to sequences by
$$a \leq b \qquad \text{iff} \qquad \forall n\colon a_n \leq b_n~.$$
We furthermore define a left-shift operator $\triangle a$ on sequences, such that
$$(\triangle a)_n = a_{n+1}~,$$
i.e. the sequence $\triangle a$ is obtained from the sequence $a$ by dropping the $0$-th element. Using this, one can show that
$$a~ \text{is an ascending chain}\qquad \text{iff}\qquad a \leq \triangle a~.$$
Question: I am interested in transfinite sequences. Is there a "shift-like" operator $\Box a$ acting on transfinite sequences such that
$$a~ \text{is an ascending (transfinite) chain}\qquad \text{iff}\qquad a \leq \Box a~?$$

Your question admits unwanted answers, where $\Box a=a$ if $a$ is ascending, otherwise something not above $a$. So presumably you want to say something more about the nature of the operator to be acceptable.

True, I did not think about that. It should be "shift-like" as was $\triangle$ for ordinary sequences, but I don't know how to formally capture that.

Shifting within each $\omega$-block does not work, since this will be equivalent to being ascending within each block, but not necessarily overall.

Yeah, I figured that one out too (but a lot slower than you).

If you can articulate the desired features of the operator that make it shift-like, then the problem will become: how to prove there is no such operator.

New answer. For any sequence $a=\langle a_\alpha\mid\alpha<\ell(a)\rangle$, define $\Box a$ to the sequence $\langle b_\alpha\mid\alpha<\ell(a)\rangle$, where $b_\alpha=\min\{a_\beta\mid\alpha<\beta\}$. It follows easily that $a$ is ascending if and only if $a\leq \Box a$.
Furthermore, if $a$ is an ascending $\omega$-sequence, then $\Box a$ is exactly the left shift of $a$.
Previous answer. Here is one way to answer, which might be something like what you want.
Suppose we are considering $\lambda$-sequences, where $\lambda$ is an indecomposable ordinal, so that $\alpha+\lambda=\lambda$ for every $\alpha<\lambda$.
Let $\Box_\alpha a$ be the shift-by-$\alpha$ sequence, which omits the first $\alpha$ many members of $a$. Then $a$ is ascending if and only if $a\leq \Box_\alpha a$ for all $\alpha<\lambda$.
This is clearly true if $a$ is ascending, and if not, then there will be a suitable shift realizing this.
You can drop the indecomposability bit if you are fine with comparing sequences of different lengths.

An ambient ordinal $\lambda$ was definitely what I was looking for. However, what I do not want is the additional $\forall$ quantifier over all $\alpha$. I'd like (if at all possible) to compare only a single time – or in other words: to compare only two objects: $a$ and $\Box a$.

You can define $\Box a$ to move everybody down to a place where it would be a violation of direct comparision, if possible. This works, but it is a bit like the ad hoc solution in my first comment, so perhaps not what you want.

Indeed, that is "obviously" not what I want. But I find it hard to capture formally why the $\triangle$ shift is "obviously" ok, whereas the two "ad-hoc" operators you describe are "obviously" not ok.

(by the way: thanks a lot for your answer anyway! :) )

Why not simply delete items in the sequence that are not larger than some previous element. This is going to be awkward to write, but it seems to give you what you want.

Might be that I have to delete all. Then I have shortened the sequence, but I don't want that. The sequence should keep its length.

About the new answer: I figured that one out, too. I'd say that this is also not as  mild an operator as $\triangle$. I.e. because $\triangle$ does something very local whereas $\Box$ needs to look back arbitrarily much.
But maybe there is no hope for anything similarly local as $\triangle$ for transfinite sequences?

@blk It will be more interesting if you are able to articulate the desired features in your operation, and the problem will become to prove there is no such operation. What counts as a shift-like operation?

I think with local I mean that there is a uniform bound $b$ such that each value of $\Box a$ can be obtained by looking at only at most $b$ values that occur in $a$. Ideally, $b$ is finite. For $\triangle a$ that bound is $b = 1$.

Also: I was wondering whether there is something sensible already known to the community of what counts as a "shift" on a transfinite sequence.

Regarding transfinite shifts, a shift is just a final segment, and this is a perfectly sensible notion for transfinite sequences. And there are only finitely many possible order types realized, as explained here: https://jdh.hamkins.org/every-ordinal-has-only-finitely-many-order-types-for-its-final-segments/
